# Interpreting "source_elapsed" column in Cassandra system table "system_traces.events"

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql, datastax, cassandra-3.0

The documentation at https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.7/cql/cql/cql_reference/cqlsh_commands/cqlshTracing.html reads

```
Note: The source_elapsed column value is the elapsed time of the event on the source node in microseconds.
```

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/18977513/1427872, it is clear that

```
source_elapsed is the cumulative execution time on a specific node
```

If that is true, can somebody explain to me how the value is 6 after 1521 for the IP 54.14.18.199 in the following response?
[image: system_traces.events Response]

Note: The IP addresses have been renamed for security

Answer (score 0):

Those lines were not generated by the same request. You can see that by looking at the `event_id` column.

By the way, I hope that you're not exposing your cluster to the Internet with public IPs.